# Follow Person Java Twitter

Tags: java, http, post, twitter

I want to successfully follow a person on twitter programatically without using the Twitter API.

I want to do this via Java. I can already successfully login via Twitter via sending an HTTP-Post with the correct credentials on Java, but, I want to successfully follow a user directly programatically too.

So I'm wondering is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [POST a request to friendships/create](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/create).

How you do that will depend on your library.

Comment: This is dependent on the Twitter API.. Again, I do not want to be dependent on their API. I essentially just want to mimic a normal twitter person clicking on a "follow" button for user. Completely independent on the Twitter API.

Comment: You *have* to use the Twitter API if you want to interact with Twitter.